# Fixing maps library data for Pacific centred (0°-360° longitude) display

Tags: r, maps

I'm plotting some points on a map of the world using the R `maps` package, something like:

[image: Map of the world, -180° to 180° longitude]

The command to draw the base map is:

```
map("world", fill=TRUE, col="white", bg="gray", ylim=c(-60, 90), mar=c(0,0,0,0))
```

But I need to display Pacific centred map. I use `map("world2",` etc to use the Pacific centred basemap from the maps package, and convert the coordinates of the data points in my dataframe (`df`) with:

```
df$longitude[df$longitude < 0] = df$longitude[df$longitude < 0] + 360
```

This works if I don't use the `fill` option, but with `fill` the polygons which cross 0° cause problems.

[image: Map of the world, 0° to 360° longitude]

I guess I need to transform the polygon data from the `maps` library somehow to sort this out, but I have no idea how to get at this.

My ideal solution would be to draw a maps with a left boundary at -20° and a right boundary at -30° (i.e. 330°). The following gets the correct points and coastlines onto the map, but the crossing-zero problem is the same

```
df$longitude[df$longitude < -20] = df$longitude[d$longitude < -20] + 360
map("world", fill=TRUE, col="white", bg="gray", mar=c(0,0,0,0),
  ylim=c(-60, 90), xlim=c(-20, 330))
map("world2", add=TRUE, col="white", bg="gray", fill=TRUE, xlim=c(180, 330))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Its because the borders don't form closed shapes becuase of where the cut is.

Comment: Here is a workaround:  Add a large, arbitrary number to df$longitude, say for example 360.  This should work, as long as you don't need to show the longitudes on a scale.  PS.  I have done this successfully using ggplot() graphics.

Comment: @James, is a closed polygon just an open polygon with the first point repeated at the end? Do you know how I can manipulate this in the maps package?

Comment: @Andrie, df is just a dataframe with the coordinates of my coloured dots: the map polygons are part of the maps library.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You can use the `map_data` function in `ggplot2` to put the data into `data.frame` format, and then check each group to see if it is closed, and add a new data point if not.

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning here that [`recenter`](https://rdrr.io/cran/sp/man/recenter-methods.html) from `sp` and [`st_shift_longitude`](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_shift_longitude.html) from `sf` packages now do this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use the fact that internally, a `map` object returned by the `map()` function can be recalculated and used again in the `map()` function. I'd create a list with individual polygons, check which ones have very different longitude values, and rearrange those ones. I gave an example of this approach in the function below*, which allows something like :

```
plot.map("world", center=180, col="white",bg="gray",
   fill=TRUE,ylim=c(-60,90),mar=c(0,0,0,0))
```

to get

[image: Corrected map center 180]

If I were you, I'd shift everything a bit more, like in :

```
plot.map("world", center=200, col="white",bg="gray",
   fill=TRUE,ylim=c(-60,90),mar=c(0,0,0,0))
```

[image: Corrected map center 200]

The function :

```
plot.map<- function(database,center,...){
    Obj <- map(database,...,plot=F)
    coord <- cbind(Obj[[1]],Obj[[2]])

    # split up the coordinates
    id <- rle(!is.na(coord[,1]))
    id <- matrix(c(1,cumsum(id$lengths)),ncol=2,byrow=T)
    polygons <- apply(id,1,function(i){coord[i[1]:i[2],]})

    # split up polygons that differ too much
    polygons <- lapply(polygons,function(x){
        x[,1] <- x[,1] + center
        x[,1] <- ifelse(x[,1]>180,x[,1]-360,x[,1])
        if(sum(diff(x[,1])>300,na.rm=T) >0){
          id <- x[,1] < 0
          x <- rbind(x[id,],c(NA,NA),x[!id,])
       }
       x
    })
    # reconstruct the object
    polygons <- do.call(rbind,polygons)
    Obj[[1]] <- polygons[,1]
    Obj[[2]] <- polygons[,2]

    map(Obj,...)
}
```

*Note that this function only takes positive center values. It's easily adapted to allow for center values in both directions, but I didn't bother anymore as that's trivial.

Comment: @Michael Dunn : You're welcome. If you ever need the names of the polygons, you'll have to adapt the function so you can double the names of the split polygons in the `$name` element of the map object.

Answer (score 5):

install the latest version of maps (3.2.0).

do this:

```
d$lon2 <- ifelse(d$lon < -25, d$lon + 360, d$lon) # where d is your df
mapWorld <- map_data('world', wrap=c(-25,335), ylim=c(-55,75))

ggplot() +
geom_polygon(data = mapWorld, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group)) +
geom_point(data = d, aes(x = lon2, y = lat))
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but you can also create a shifted map by using a projection (requires the mapproj package):

```
  map("world", projection="rectangular", parameter=0, 
      orientation=c(90,0,180), wrap=TRUE, fill=T, resolution=0,col=0)
```

This will shift by 180 degrees. But the difference with 'world2' is that the longitude co-ordinate will be different ([-pi,pi]). All projections of this package put 0 at the centre. And in that case, the 'wrap' option detects the jump correctly.

'resolution=0' helps to get cleaner borders.

You can easily change the centre longitude by changing the '180' value in the projection description.

Comment: as mentioned in another answer, as of maps 3.2 there is now a simpler way to get the same result without projection: map("world", wrap=c(-90,270), ...). So 'wrap' is not boolean but a vector. Funnily enough, I think it was answering this question originally that set me thinking about implementing that better wrapping code.

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution?

```
xlims = c(0, 359) # these are the limits you want to change
ylims = c(-55,75)

mapWorld <- map_data('world', wrap=xlims, ylim=ylims)
head(mapWorld)

g1 <- ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = mapWorld, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group)) +
    coord_map("rectangular", lat0=0, xlim=xlims, ylim=ylims)

g1
```