# Use different center than the prime meridian in plotting a world map

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am overlaying a world map from the `maps` package onto a `ggplot2` raster geometry. However, this raster is not centered on the prime meridian (0 deg), but on 180 deg (roughly the Bering Sea and the Pacific). The following code gets the map and recenters the map on 180 degree:

```
require(maps)
world_map = data.frame(map(plot=FALSE)[c("x","y")])
names(world_map) = c("lon","lat")
world_map = within(world_map, {
  lon = ifelse(lon < 0, lon + 360, lon)
})
ggplot(aes(x = lon, y = lat), data = world_map) + geom_path()
```

which yields the following output:

[image]

Quite obviously there are the lines draw between polygons that are on one end or the other of the prime meridian. My current solution is to replace points close to the prime meridian by NA, replacing the `within` call above by:

```
world_map = within(world_map, {
  lon = ifelse(lon < 0, lon + 360, lon)
  lon = ifelse((lon < 1) | (lon > 359), NA, lon)
})
ggplot(aes(x = lon, y = lat), data = world_map) + geom_path()
```

Which leads to the correct image. I now have a number of question:

1. There must be a better way of centering the map on another meridian. I tried using the `orientation` parameter in `map`, but setting this to `orientation = c(0,180,0)` did not yield the correct result, in fact it did not change anything to the result object (`all.equal` yielded `TRUE`).
2. Getting rid of the horizontal stripes should be possible without deleting some of the polygons. It might be that solving point 1. also solves this point.

Comment: If you're just interested in centring the map around 180 deg., the map "world2" in the `maps` package or a high-resolution version "world2Hires" in the `mapdata` package are already centered on 180 deg. The rest of your code works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I am still interested in a flexible solution though.

Comment: Are you only interested in a ggplot solution? I would do most of this using `sp` and related packages, but don't know anything about converting `sp`'s `Spatial*` objects (especially the raster-representing ones) to ggplot...

Comment: Sp classes to something ggplot2 can use is quite easy. So I'm open to sp based answers.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra -- Cool. I just posted my entry. Have to say I look forward to the day when something better than the `maps` package comes along. It's been an invaluable workhorse, but man is it ever quirky/buggy!

Comment: @PaulHiemstra -- Is this (from a month or two previous) also a solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353184/fixing-maps-library-data-for-pacific-centred-0-360-longitude-display

Comment: Looks like it could easily be adapted to yield a data.frame for ggplot2, thanks!

Comment: `sp::recenter` helped me a lot for a similar issue!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a different approach. It works by:

1. Converting the world map from the `maps` package into a `SpatialLines` object with a geographical (lat-long) CRS.
2. Projecting the `SpatialLines` map into the Plate Carée (aka Equidistant Cylindrical) projection centered on the Prime Meridian. (This projection is very similar to a geographical mapping).
3. Cutting in two segments that would otherwise be clipped by left and right edges of the map. (This is done using topological functions from the `rgeos` package.)
4. Reprojecting to a Plate Carée projection centered on the desired meridian (`lon_0` in terminology taken from the `PROJ_4` program used by `spTransform()` in the `rgdal` package).
5. Identifying (and removing) any remaining 'streaks'. I automated this by searching for lines that cross g.e. two of three widely separated meridians. (This also uses topological functions from the `rgeos` package.)

This is obviously a lot of work, but leaves one with maps that are minimally truncated, and can be easily reprojected using `spTransform()`. To overlay these on top of raster images with `base` or `lattice` graphics, I first reproject the rasters, also using `spTransform()`. If you need them, grid lines and labels can likewise be projected to match the `SpatialLines` map.

---

```
library(sp)
library(maps)
library(maptools)   ## map2SpatialLines(), pruneMap()
library(rgdal)      ## CRS(), spTransform()
library(rgeos)      ## readWKT(), gIntersects(), gBuffer(), gDifference() 

## Convert a "maps" map to a "SpatialLines" map
makeSLmap <- function() {
    llCRS <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84")
    wrld <- map("world", interior = FALSE, plot=FALSE,
            xlim = c(-179, 179), ylim = c(-89, 89))
    wrld_p <- pruneMap(wrld, xlim = c(-179, 179))
    map2SpatialLines(wrld_p, proj4string = llCRS)
}

## Clip SpatialLines neatly along the antipodal meridian
sliceAtAntipodes <- function(SLmap, lon_0) {
    ## Preliminaries
    long_180 <- (lon_0 %% 360) - 180
    llCRS  <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84")  ## CRS of 'maps' objects
    eqcCRS <- CRS("+proj=eqc")
    ## Reproject the map into Equidistant Cylindrical/Plate Caree projection 
    SLmap <- spTransform(SLmap, eqcCRS)
    ## Make a narrow SpatialPolygon along the meridian opposite lon_0
    L  <- Lines(Line(cbind(long_180, c(-89, 89))), ID="cutter")
    SL <- SpatialLines(list(L), proj4string = llCRS)
    SP <- gBuffer(spTransform(SL, eqcCRS), 10, byid = TRUE)
    ## Use it to clip any SpatialLines segments that it crosses
    ii <- which(gIntersects(SLmap, SP, byid=TRUE))
    # Replace offending lines with split versions
    # (but skip when there are no intersections (as, e.g., when lon_0 = 0))
    if(length(ii)) { 
        SPii <- gDifference(SLmap[ii], SP, byid=TRUE)
        SLmap <- rbind(SLmap[-ii], SPii)  
    }
    return(SLmap)
}

## re-center, and clean up remaining streaks
recenterAndClean <- function(SLmap, lon_0) {
    llCRS <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84")  ## map package's CRS
    newCRS <- CRS(paste("+proj=eqc +lon_0=", lon_0, sep=""))
    ## Recenter 
    SLmap <- spTransform(SLmap, newCRS)
    ## identify remaining 'scratch-lines' by searching for lines that
    ## cross 2 of 3 lines of longitude, spaced 120 degrees apart
    v1 <-spTransform(readWKT("LINESTRING(-62 -89, -62 89)", p4s=llCRS), newCRS)
    v2 <-spTransform(readWKT("LINESTRING(58 -89, 58 89)",   p4s=llCRS), newCRS)
    v3 <-spTransform(readWKT("LINESTRING(178 -89, 178 89)", p4s=llCRS), newCRS)
    ii <- which((gIntersects(v1, SLmap, byid=TRUE) +
                 gIntersects(v2, SLmap, byid=TRUE) +
                 gIntersects(v3, SLmap, byid=TRUE)) >= 2)
    SLmap[-ii]
}

## Put it all together:
Recenter <- function(lon_0 = -100, grid=FALSE, ...) {                        
    SLmap <- makeSLmap()
    SLmap2 <- sliceAtAntipodes(SLmap, lon_0)
    recenterAndClean(SLmap2, lon_0)
}

## Try it out
par(mfrow=c(2,2), mar=rep(1, 4))
plot(Recenter(-90), col="grey40"); box() ## Centered on 90w 
plot(Recenter(0),   col="grey40"); box() ## Centered on prime meridian
plot(Recenter(90),  col="grey40"); box() ## Centered on 90e
plot(Recenter(180), col="grey40"); box() ## Centered on International Date Line
```

[image]

Comment: This is great and works a treat.  Is there a way to do something similar with a SpatialPolygons object so we can keep the country border information?

Comment: @PeterEllis -- That's what I first tried, using (IIRC) `rgeos`' `gBuffer()` to make a thin vertical polygon along the splitting meridian, and then `gDifference()` to cut the SpatialPolygons that it crossed. Unfortunately, `rgeos`' polygon-checking standards are too high, & it rejected any SpatialPolygons I could create from the `map` object, with messages about invalid topologies etc. I banged my head against the wall for too long trying to fix the polygons, so if you figure anything out, please do let me know! Alternatively, does the solution I linked in comments to the question above work?

Comment: When I run the code here it fails unless you add a byid=T argument to the gBuffer function, i.e.:SP <- gBuffer(spTransform(SL, eqcCRS), 10,byid=T)

Answer (score 31):

This may be somewhat tricky but you can do by:

```
mp1 <- fortify(map(fill=TRUE, plot=FALSE))
mp2 <- mp1
mp2$long <- mp2$long + 360
mp2$group <- mp2$group + max(mp2$group) + 1
mp <- rbind(mp1, mp2)
ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), data = mp) + 
  geom_path() + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 360))
```

[image]

By this setup you can easily set the center (i.e., limits):

```
ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), data = mp) + 
  geom_path() + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-100, 260))
```

[image]

**UPDATED**

Here I put some explanations:

The whole data looks like:

```
ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), data = mp) + geom_path()
```

[image]

but by `scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 360))`, you can *crop* a subset of the region from 0 to 360 longitude.

And in `geom_path`, the data of same group are connected. So if `mp2$group <- mp2$group + max(mp2$group) + 1` is absent, it looks like:
[image]

Comment: any chance of sketching how that actually works (to a curious non-r-user)?

Comment: +1, works nicely! Although I am still curious if I can prevent tinkereing with the output of `map`, and specifying it by changing the input of `map`.

Comment: As `map(orientation = c(90, 0, 180), projection="mercator")` also fails, there may be no way.

Comment: Great solution.  Is there a way to make it work if you want to map fill to country as well?

Comment: thanks for this great solution (5 years after you answered), just to point out you could change the scale from scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 360)) to coord_map(xlim = c(0, 360)).  It will avoid problems if someone decides to use polygons.  An example would be here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47021117/ggplot2-polygon-world-map-centred-with-limits-gives-funny-edges/47021283#47021283

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
 wm <- map.wrap(map(projection="rectangular", parameter=0, orientation=c(90,0,180), plot=FALSE))
world_map <- data.frame(wm[c("x","y")])
names(world_map) <- c("lon","lat")
```

The map.wrap cuts the lines going across the map. It can be used via an option to map(wrap=TRUE), but that only works when plot=TRUE.

One remaining annoyance is that at this point, lat/lon are in rad, not degrees:

```
world_map$lon <- world_map$lon * 180/pi + 180
world_map$lat <- world_map$lat * 180/pi
ggplot(aes(x = lon, y = lat), data = world_map) + geom_path()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although it does not use `ggplot2`.

Comment: Oops, true. You can substitute it in the original code, but, annoyingly, it would currently require setting plot=TRUE first, because wrap=TRUE is only used if the data is plotted.