# Plot Pacific Ocean and continents with ggplot2::borders()

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I would like to use `ggplot::borders()` showing the Pacific Ocean. My issue is that I cannot figure out how to show Australia and Asia to the west and the Americas to the east.

```
ggplot() + borders() + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-290, -70))
```

In the resulting figure, Asia and Australia should be shown but they're not.

[image: no asia and australia]

I would like to do something along the lines of this:

```
ggplot() + borders() + borders(x = long - 360)
```

to get a map like this:

[image: world map]

Can anybody help me figure this out? There are answers on SO for the `maps` and `ggmap` packages, but I could not find an answer using `ggplot2::borders()`.

One important aspect of any answer is that the lat-lon values are correct. The challenge is: with traditional longitude coordinates, a view of the Pacific will start with increasing positive values (E hemisphere) then switch to decreasing negative values at the antimeridian (W hemisphere). How can I plot this in R preferably `borders()`?

[image: convention]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to zoom it a bit to match more closely what you posted (code below). Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10629246/1305688) by [kohske](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314020/kohske)

[image: ggplot2 map pacific]

```
# install.packages("mapdata", dependencies = TRUE)
# install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
library(mapdata)

mp1 <- fortify(map(fill=TRUE, plot=FALSE))
mp2 <- mp1
mp2$long <- mp2$long + 360
mp2$group <- mp2$group + max(mp2$group) + 1
mp <- rbind(mp1, mp2)
ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), data = mp) + 
  geom_path()  + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(110, 300)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-50, 70))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I updated my question specifying a need for the correct longitude values.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
library(sp)
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

world <- map("world", fill=TRUE, col="transparent", plot=FALSE)
worldSpP <- map2SpatialPolygons(world, world$names, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84"))
worldSpP <- worldSpP[-grep("Antarctica", row.names(worldSpP)),]
worldSpP <- worldSpP[-grep("Ghana", row.names(worldSpP)),]
worldSpP <- worldSpP[-grep("UK:Great Britain", row.names(worldSpP)),]
worldSpPnr <- nowrapRecenter(worldSpP)

world_map <- fortify(worldSpPnr)

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=world_map, map=world_map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                    color="black", fill="white", size=0.25)
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I updated my question specifying a need for the correct longitude values.