# Using imported PNG images with ggmap

Tags: r, png, raster, ggmap

I think ggmap is a great package, but feel limited by it's get_map() function only working with three mapping services, and that the default format for acquired maps is square.

So I'd like to import a PNG file of the US from [here](http://openstreetmap.gryph.de/bigmap.cgi?xmin=4&xmax=11&ymin=10&ymax=13&zoom=5&scale=256&baseurl=http://tile.openstreetmap.org/!z/!x/!y.png), and since I'm pretty facile with ggplot2—at least with regards to bioinformatics visualization—would like to overplot healthcare data on this map.

The bounding box info are:
Map is 8x4 tiles (2048x1024 px) at zoom 5, aspect 2.0:1
Bbox is -135.00, 21.94, -45.00, 55.78 (l,b,r,t)

I know another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13222504/2373783) touches on the issue, but probably because I'm a genomics person rather than a GIS person, I'm not quite crossing the finish line...

Common sense seems to tell me that all I need to do is assign the bounding latitudes and longitudes to this PNG file (after rasterizing) in order to get be off to the races, and that's where I'm stuck.

I've done just fine using the get_maps() function and plotting a limited geographic area with geom_point(), but I'd like to be able to do this with rectangular and non-Google API limited info too.

Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be ggmap? It's easy enough with other tools

Comment: @mdsumner: I guess not. If other approaches get me to a lat/long bounded raster, I suppose I can figure out where to go from there. Thanks.