# ggmap: Can't find a world map to use with plotted locations

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, ggmap

I would like to plot cities of the world, over a map of the world using ggmap.

I have the cities of the world plotting fine.  But the backdrop of a world map is a lot more difficult than I thought.

My code is as follows:

```
map1 <- openmap(c(70,-179),
              c(-70,179),zoom=1)
map1 <- openproj(map)


reclat <- c(50,20,30,40)
reclong <- c(30,40,30,50)        
autoplot(map1) + geom_point(aes(x=reclong,y=reclat))
qmplot(long,lat,data=world.cities,colour=I('red'), size = I(3), darken = .3)
```

This may sound vague, but I have absolutely no idea how to create some sort of 'background' that is actually a world map!

I have been reading the documentation and looking at examples, but I can't find a solution.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Here is a map that the code produces:
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the maps package?  Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201997/world-map-with-ggmap

Comment: I attempted a bit of cannibalization of that code at one point, but it didn't seem to work with my data too well...didn't seem to be a straightforward way to switcheroo my long and lat data.  But I will keep trying..

Comment: Strange that this is so difficult. Do you have to use `ggmap`? Otherwise you could just do `library(maps); map();` and away you go. Your intended plot doesn't sound like it needs anything too advanced.

Comment: ?get_map says "maps of the whole world currently not supported"

Comment: @thelatemail `maps` still has USSR on its world map; `rworldmap` is way more recent.

Comment: so I'm realizing that maps is outdated and ggplot has no world map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `rworldmap` and base graphics:

```
library(rworldmap)
plot(getMap())
points(world.cities$long,world.cities$lat,col="red")
```

Comment: Not the nicest looking thing but fits the bill.

Comment: Not R-patriotic, but my current patent for nice-looking maps is to export stuff I want to show into GeoJSON and render the picture with TileMill.

Answer (score 0):

The package 'maps' does it for you

```
library(maps)
map()
```