# ggmap renders blank map

Tags: r, ggmap

I am trying to plot few points on map. But I get a blank map with just the points marked in red. The map is missing

Below code is reporducible

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

lon <- c(-122.1817252,-119.4179324,-95.7128910,-71.0588801,-81.0348144)
lat <- c(37.452960,36.778261,37.090240,42.360082,34.000710)

all_places_geocoded <- data.frame(lon,lat)

gc <- geocode('australia')
center <- as.numeric(gc)

map <- get_googlemap(location = center,maptype = "roadmap", zoom=1)

ggmap(map) + 
  geom_point(data = all_places_geocoded, color = "red3", size = 1)
```

Comment: `zoom` has to be between 3 and 21 - see help file

Comment: Thanks!! I got my map but it shows only data of US. How can I get world map. I have points from across the world

Comment: not sure you can with ggmap. I would use `map_data(map = "world")` and then `geom_map`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201997/world-map-with-ggmap